# Ruby class override without inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I've just made this experiment:

```
class A < Hash
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

class A < Hash
  def bar 
    'bar'
  end
end
```

So far I get the result I expected, the second declaration extends the first one. However I was surprised of this:

```
class A
  def call
    puts foo
    puts bar
  end
end
```

The code above works, but only if I declare it later. Otherwise I get:

```
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class A
```

Can I assume that in Ruby, it is safe skipping the superclass specification without side effects after making sure that the "original-first" declaration was parsed?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In you last attempt, it tries to make an `Object` class, as its superclass.. So the error you got.. and it is expected..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to declare inheritance only on the first occurince of the class definition, so below variants will work:

1. When you've defined the same class inheritance:

   ```
   class A < Hash
   end

   class A < Hash
   end
   ```
2. When you've used default inheritance in the second case, that is treated as undefined inheritance:

   ```
   class A < Hash
   end

   class A
   end
   ```
3. When you've used default inheritance in both cases, the default inheritance is of `Object` class:

   ```
   class A
   end

   class A
   end
   ```

And below will not:

1. When you've used default inheritance in the first case, and next you tried to redefine it explicitly:

   ```
   class A
   end

   class A < Hash
   end

   TypeError: superclass mismatch for class A
   ```
2. When you've used specified inheritance (in example `String`) in the first case, and next you tried to redefine it explicitly (in example with `Hash`):

   ```
   class A < String
   end

   class A < Hash
   end

   TypeError: superclass mismatch for class A
   ```

Answer (score 1):

[**@Малъ Скрылевъ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21483528/2767755) explained this case a better way, so I wouldn't attempt that. But I would show you another way to do this.

One way to avoid the error is in your situation :

Instead of writing

```
class A
  def call
    puts foo
    puts bar
  end
end
```

Write it as below using [`Module#class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval):

> Evaluates the string or block in the context of mod, except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected. *This can be used to add methods to a class*. `module_eval` returns the result of evaluating its argument.

```
A.class_eval do
  def _call
    puts foo
    puts bar
  end
end
```